# Decoding JSON and a base64-encoded value in a shell script

Tags: json, shell, base64, decode

I have a JSON and I need to extract a base64-encoded value by particular key and decode it.

JSON has the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "LockIndex": 0,
    "Key": "Arul/key1",
    "Flags": 0,
    "Value": "MzAKCg==",
    "CreateIndex": 369,
    "ModifyIndex": 554
  }
]
```

In the above JSON, I need to extract only `"Value":"MzAKCg=="` and decode the base64-encoded `"MzAKCg=="` value. I would like to perform this using shell scripting.

Please assist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.com/jq/) and [`base64`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/base64):

```
jq -r '.[].Value' < file.json | base64 --decode
```

Comment: This works if you're trying to decode one value at a time, but if you have an object of values (e.g., `{"secret": {"DB_USERNAME": "<base64-encoded>", "DB_PASSWORD": "<base64-encoded>"}}`) then this doesn't work very well. Note that this isn't a contrived case, but rather the way Kubernetes secrets are structured.

Answer (score 33):

jq has recently added support for base64 encoding and decoding

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Formatstringsandescaping

> @base64:
>
> The input is converted to base64 as specified by RFC 4648.
>
> @base64d:
>
> The inverse of @base64, input is decoded as specified by RFC 4648.
>   Note: If the decoded string is not UTF-8, the results are undefined.

For your data, the command would be

```
jq -r 'map(.Value | @base64d)' < file.json
```

---

https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/47

It's not released yet, but you can install the latest development version to use it.

```
brew reinstall --HEAD jq
```

Once the next version of jq is released then you can switch back to the latest stable version.

Comment: Note that if you have an object whose values are base64-encoded (e.g., a Kubernetes secret), you can use `.data | map_values(@base64d)`.

Comment: this ALMOST solved my problem... but (by the doc you linked and tests here) `@base64d` only works for UTF-8 stuff, and I need to deal with UTF-16 content. Damn, almost. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me: `curl --silent localhost:8500/v1/kv/key1 | jq -r '.[0].Value | @base64d'`

Answer (score 3):

use built-in in jq base64 decoder:

`echo '{"val" : "MzAKCg=="}' | jq -r '.val |=@base64d'`

yields:

`{ "val": "30\n\n" }`

**side note**: `jq` is simply a file symbolic for `jq-win64.exe`

Answer (score 1):

if this JSON will have always the same structure, you can use cut -d and later decode the value, for example:

```
$echo "Value": "MzAKCg==" | cut -d ":" -f 2 | base64 -D
```

30

Answer (score 1):

if you want to keep the origin struct, you could use like `jq -r '.|=map(.key|=@base64d)`

Answer (score 0):

With [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
xidel -s input.json -e '$json()/binary-to-string(base64Binary(Value))'
```

or

```
xidel -s input.json -e 'binary-to-string(base64Binary($json//Value))'
```